# How to read all items on the Start menu

Tags: c#, windows

How can I get a list of all the shortcuts/programs in the start menu using C#?

I had to do this recently and surprisingly couldn't find a question for it anywhere on SO so thought I would share how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code reads the files from the special folder then LINQ to split the full pathname based upon the backslash character and takes the last element to get just the filename. It then splits the filename based upon the full stop (period) character and takes the first element to get the filename minus the extension.

Note the only difference between the All Users and Current User is the SpecialFolder name which is either `CommonStartMenu` or `StartMenu`.

### Current User Start Menu

```
        string startmenu = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu);
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(startmenu, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => x.Split('\\').Last().Split('.').First());

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

### All Users Start Menu

```
        string startmenu = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu);
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(startmenu, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => x.Split('\\').Last().Split('.').First());

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```